# Java17 GC(G1) releases heap memory in Win Server 2016 despite setup of MaxHeapSize=MinHeapSize and MaxHeapFreeRatio=100

Tags: garbage-collection, windows-server-2016, java-17, g1gc

I'm using Java 17 and I've setup javaw options -Xmx16384m -Xms16384m -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=100 in order to avoid the release of heap memory to Win OS by GC(G1).
With Win server 2008R2 it works fine but with Win 2016 (v 1607 build 14393.5989) the JVM is releasing the application memory to OS causing during heavy calculations getting memory back from OS which is leading to too high **Sys=0.xxs** value in comparison with **User** and **Real** values in the G1 log file.

Can some experts in G1 advise some other options to play with which are specific to Java17 and Win server 2016?

Thank you in advance.